# Error in converting a PDF file page to PPM using pdftoppm

Tags: command-line, pdftoppm

I am having trouble converting a PDF file to PPM using pdftoppm.exe. The PDF file has multiple pages, and I want to convert only page 6 of the file. I have tried the following but it inexplicably fails to do the conversion:

```
pdftoppm "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/folder1/502.pdf" "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/folder1/502" -png -f 6

pdftoppm "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/folder1/502.pdf" "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/folder1/502" -png -f 6 -l 6

pdftoppm "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/folder1/502.pdf" "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/folder1/502" -png -f 6 -l 6 -singlepage
```

Answer (score 0):

After several minutes of trial and error, it appears the syntax I used was wrong. This worked for me:

```
pdftoppm -f 6 -l 6 "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\folder1\502.pdf" 502
```